# Problem with brownie

Tags: ganache, brownie

when deploying the contract

it gives me

**<function deploy_simple_storage at 0x0000021D6E255670>**

What does that mean?

**Deploy.py**

```
from brownie import accounts,config,SimpleStorage


def deploy_simple_storage():
 ##local ganache -cli
 account=accounts[0]

 simple_storage=SimpleStorage.deploy({"from":account})
 stored_value=simple_storage.retrieve()
 print(stored_value)




def main():
 print(deploy_simple_storage)
```

Terminal after using brownie run scripts/deploy.py

```
INFO: Could not find files for the given pattern(s).
Brownie v1.19.3 - Python development framework for Ethereum

BrownieWeb3Project is the active project.

Launching 'ganache-cli.cmd --chain.vmErrorsOnRPCResponse true --server.port 8545 --miner.blockGasLimit 12000000 --wallet.totalAccounts 10 --hardfork istanbul --wallet.mnemonic brownie'...

Running 'scripts\deploy.py::main'...
<function deploy_simple_storage at 0x0000021D6E255670>
Terminating local RPC client...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not actually calling the python function.  Instead, you are printing out the function signature.

Simply change to

```
def main():
 deploy_simple_storage()
```

There is no reason to put a print around the function since it does not return anything.